# How to re-write %3f to ? in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Most of our pages are accessed by query string, so our URLs look like this:

http://www.example.com/?var=val&var2=val2

I found that somewhere on the web, someone has linked back to us with links like this:

http://www.example.com/%3Fvar%3Dval%26var2%3Dval2

I found a large block of [code](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4138119.htm) to add to my .htaccess file, but it REALLY slowed down my page requests. What I'd like is to just catch that "%" at the beginning of the filename and redirect it to a php file where I can parse it into a query string and 301 redirect it.

I have a feeling that if I knew what I was doing this would actually be a pretty easy thing. Let's presume that my php file will be called percent_fix.php

(I am sure I can write the php, I just need help with the .htaccess rewrite condition and rule.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went back to the link I included in my question, and realized that the simple case near the top of that thread actually does what I need.
Here's what actually work for me:

```
#in .htaccess
RewriteEngine on

# If an encoded "?" is present in the requested URI, and no unencoded "?" is
# present, then externally redirect to replace the encoded "?" character.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^?\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %1 ^(([^%]*(\%(25)*([^3].|.[^F]))*)*)\%(25)*3F(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^. http://www.example.com/percent_fix.php?%7 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Then in percent_fix.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
  {
    $new_query=urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/?'.$new_query);
    die();
  }
else
  {
    header('HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found');
    //readfile("http://www.example.com/?page=404_error");
    die();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your default page to your links. e.g. index.php

Then add to your .htaccess

```
# for %3f ...
RewriteRule ^/index.php\?(.*)$ /index.php?$1
```

Comment: I do it in this way: RewriteRule ^/(.*)\?(.*)$ /$1?$2 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly getting a 403 error. 
The error is caused because ? is a banned file/directory name character on Windows and Linux. This means when Apache attempts to find a file or directory named "/document/root/index.php?blah" (after decoding) and it causes a 403 error. This is before the .htaccess files are read so you cannot use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file to override this 403 error or an ErrorDocument defined in the .htaccess file to catch this error.

**The only way to catch %3f is to use mod_rewrite or an ErrorDocument in a "VirtualHost"** e.g. in httpd-vhosts.conf (or the main server configuration if there aren't any "Virtualhost"s e.g. in httpd.conf).

Answer (score -1):

try the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: you may need to use \% instead of % as %{xxx} means apache variable xxx

Comment: I tried it as written and tried \%. Neither one did the job. I then tried variations on  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^[%]` right before the rule and couldn't get it to work. Still looking.

Comment: I've setup my machine with mod_rewrite logging and changed my answer to one that worked for me

Comment: @TecBrat: I've reviewed and rejected your suggested edit of this answer. If you want to answer your own question, feel free to do so. But don't make such major edits to other people's answers...

Comment: the logs suggest that apache has decoded the url to ?var=val&var2=val2 so checking for % would fail

Comment: @LukasEder Understood. I think I'll do that. It just seems wierd to me to ask AND answer a question. Don't want someone to think ill of be because of it.

Comment: @TecBrat: Don't worry. It happens all the time. Even if you answer your own question, future visitors may find valuable information in this question